# Installing 1.12 version on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

This page works as expected if I choose **Ubuntu 14.04 image**.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/cloud/cloud-ex-aws/

But If I choose Amazon Linux AMI, (the first one in the list shown in the image) then I am not able to install 1.12 version of docker.

I can however install older version using ...

```
yum install docker
```

But I am trying to install the latest 1.12 version on Amazon Linux AMI. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of mid-October 2016, this is not possible: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27313

Long story short, it appears that there needs to be some coordination between the AWS & Docker folks and that coordination hasn't happened yet: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/17283#issuecomment-163456402

Couple options:

1. Wait until that process completes and a new AWS Linux AMI is released where when you could just run `$ sudo yum install -y docker` and be more or less up & running w/ 1.12
2. Select a different AMI which will require additional installation/config depending on your requirements

ex. You mentioned you tried the Ubuntu 14.04 AMI. If you SSH'd to that instance & tried to copy some large files from S3 and unzip them on the host machine in order to mount them as volumes into your containers, you'd have a problem. The Ubuntu 14.04 AMI doesn't have the aws-cli tool installed nor the "unzip" command out of the box (nor docker for that matter)-- so you'd need to read over http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-bundle-other-os and run `$ sudo apt-get unzip` in order to get up and running. The AWS Linux AMI has a lot more bells & whistles out of the box. If you don't mind the config work and using a slightly different repository system, this isn't a bad option in the meantime.)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get Docker 1.12.2 running on Amazon Linux. Here are the steps I took:

Download the version of Docker you want to your Amazon Linux instance (as a gzipped tar), and extract it. This creates a directory called `docker/` containing Docker binaries.

```
wget https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.12.2.tgz
tar -xvzf docker-1.12.2.tgz
```

Move all the Docker binaries into `/usr/local/bin`.

```
sudo mv docker/* /usr/local/bin/
```

You need to run a script called `cgroupfs-mount` (as superuser) before starting up the Docker daemon. The easiest way to get this script is by cloning the git repo containing it.

```
git clone https://github.com/tianon/cgroupfs-mount
sudo mv cgroupfs-mount/cgroupfs-mount /usr/local/bin/
```

Change to the superuser and make sure that `/usr/local/bin/` is in your path (on Amazon Linux at least this is not the case by default).

```
sudo su
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Now you can run the cgroupfs-mount script and start the Docker daemon (as a background process).

```
cgroupfs-mount
dockerd &
```

You can call regular Docker commands (e.g. `docker pull`) as any user who belongs to the `docker` group, while `dockerd` is running. Missing from these installation steps is having `cgroupfs-mount` and `dockerd` be automatically run at start up time.

As an aside, I would recommend avoiding Amazon Linux if at all possible and using a mainstream distro like Ubuntu or CentOS instead, which seem to have much better support for Docker.

Comment: Upvote for this since as of now 1.12.x has been deprecated but this answer still works as of today!

Answer (score 4):

**Update: January 2017**

Amazon offer docker 1.12 in repository of updates (amzn-updates).

I have installed `docker-1.12.6-1.17.amzn1.x86_64`

Comment: how do you install that?

Comment: try with: yum update && yum install docker-1.12.6-1.17 as root.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your manual steps don't work but you can install the docker daemon using `docker-machine`.

```
VM_OPTS="--driver amazonec2 
--amazonec2-ami $YOUR-AMI
--amazonec2-instance-type t2.medium
--amazonec2-access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
--amazonec2-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
--amazonec2-ssh-keypath $AWS_SSH_KEYPATH
--amazonec2-region ap-southeast-2
--amazonec2-zone a
--amazonec2-security-group $YOUR_SEC_GROUP_NAME"

docker-machine create $VM_OPTS $VM_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also install it from the command line of the instance using the following:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Comment: On Amazon Linux instances the command above runs 'yum -y -q install docker', which is essentially the same command as the original question. This command installs 1.11.2 (at this time).

Answer (score 0):

(like in [How to upgrade docker in latest Amazon linux AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030256/how-to-upgrade-docker-in-latest-amazon-linux-ami/47096990#47096990) )

https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/amazonlinux/
The latest Amazon Linux 2017.09 seems to have Docker version 17.06.2-ce