# How to upgrade docker in latest Amazon linux AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-opsworks, amazon-linux, docker-aws

I am using Amazon linux AMI in Opsworks and the Amazon linux AMI are the latest one (OS Amazon Linux 2017.03).

The issue is that this AMI comes with docker version **17.03.2-ce**, however I need to install version **17.05** or later (because I want to modify "ingress" network in docker swarm which is only possible in the latest docker versions.)

Looks like [Amazon officially supports version](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/amazonlinux/) only till 17.03.

If I try to upgrade the docker manually from the centos rpm/repository, I get the following error(possibly because I an in Redhat flavour and docker doesn't seem to support that at the moment):

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
       Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
       Requires: systemd-units
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
       Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
       Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

**cat /proc/version**

```
Linux version 4.9.43-17.38.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-60008) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) )
```

Is there anyway I can upgrade the docker version without having to wait for the Amazon release?

Comment: Does not look good - I spend a couple of hours trying and could not make all packages work.
Other people are trying it on RHEL and cannot make it work either:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272827/docker-ce-on-rhel-requires-container-selinux-2-9

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/amazonlinux/

The latest Amazon Linux 2017.09 has Docker version 17.06.2-ce